# SQL Query that searches for "none of these words"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a query and get results where a specific word is not in the search result.

any idea how I can do this?

I am using SQL Server 2012

Table 1: Customer Info

```
First Name
Last Name
Customer ID
Report
```

I want to search for data in the Report field. That is a `NVARCHAR` data type.

so in my example, I want to find all the reports that do not contain the word "foreclosure"

Comment: Have you seen the [EXISTS condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) ?

Comment: Need more info on tables and columns.

Comment: Please post your table structure, sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE [field name] NOT IN ("word1","word2","...")

WHERE [field name] NOT LIKE '%@myword%'

WHERE @myword NOT IN [field name]
```

etc.

EDIT

```
WHERE [Report] NOT LIKE '%foreclosure%'
```

Otherwise, check out CHARINDEX or any number of other string functions in Books Online.

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting of your answer?

Comment: why would someone want to use the MINUS Query? select supplier_id
from suppliers
MINUS
select supplier_id
from orders;

Comment: @CocoaDev -- that's a different flavor of SQL.  I'm not sure which all use `MINUS`, but Oracle's version of it (PLSQL) is similar to Microsoft's (TSQL) `EXCEPT`.  In any case, look it up in Books Online -- seriously -- it's a terrific resource when you're trying to get started.